# Como sumar todos los valores de una columna - Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

quisiera saber como sumar todos los datos de una columna de mi base de datos.

Este es mi modelo:

**models.py**

```
class Model(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    number = models.FloatField(default=0)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
```

Quisiera obtener la suma de todos los datos del campo number para despues realizar una operacion, los métodos que conozco son los siguientes pero no se como usarlos:

```
obj.aggregate(Sum('number')
```

Quiero realizar algo asi pero no se como aplicarlo:

```
obj = Model.objects.all().filter(user=request.user)
obj.number

variable_1 = 10    
variable_1 = 10 + obj.number  # La suma de todos los registros del campo number
```

muchas gracias amigos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Te recomiendo que revises la [documentación](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/aggregation/#cheat-sheet). Lo que quieres hacer se obtiene con la suguiente consulta:

```
from django.db.models import Sum
Model.objects.all().aggregate(Sum('number'))
```

El resultado es un diccionario que se ve mas o menos así:

```
{'number__sum': 10}
```

Si lo asignas a una variable, lo usarías de esta manera:

```
obj = Model.objects.all().aggregate(Sum('number'))
obj['number__sum'] += 1
print (obj)
>>> {'number__sum': 11}
```